# Convert NSString to NSDictionary - jsonserialization error 3840

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I have a string on description gives following as output-  `@"{\n    \"40147089-db8b-4223-89ab-7a2f72ac57d6\" =     {\n        \"22337b85-d2cf-4079-8d5f-9804cb680f2c\" =         (\n            yes\n        );\n        \"87eeb49f-b34a-431b-8701-bd7f36bc91ea\" =         (\n            yes\n        );\n    };\n    \"7262d43c-4d72-4e71-9097-6db5632d1f54\" =     {\n        \"22337b85-d2cf-4079-8d5f-9804cb680f2c\" =         (\n            yes\n        );\n        \"58ecb861-4372-412b-8740-a9f94260ed93\" =         (\n            yes\n        );\n    };\n}"`

How do I convert it to `NSDictionary`? always jsonserialisation is throwing me Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value for key in object around character 45."

So this is what I get on printing ResponseObj where ResponseObj is of type id

po responseObject

```
{
"159476cc-3e1f-4995-bf23-df41141dd8c5" = 2;
"6280ecfe-841e-4a35-8002-3e9e7327ba7d" = 2;
"64de3fc6-ff59-4e91-a2e7-f3ec904eecce" =     {
    "40147089-db8b-4223-89ab-7a2f72ac57d6" =         {
        "22337b85-d2cf-4079-8d5f-9804cb680f2c" =             (
            yes
        );
        "87eeb49f-b34a-431b-8701-bd7f36bc91ea" =             (
            yes
        );
    };
    "7262d43c-4d72-4e71-9097-6db5632d1f54" =         {
        "22337b85-d2cf-4079-8d5f-9804cb680f2c" =             (
            yes
        );
        "58ecb861-4372-412b-8740-a9f94260ed93" =             (
            yes
        );
    };
};
"83ec5c05-cb2f-4c49-b9a3-ab44c487bf55" =     {
    "2a8dd370-2f7e-4c8e-93d5-21102fbc82fd" =         {
        "957bdaba-b23d-4243-8384-62dfa46f0656" = work;
    };
    "b3e0aded-d57b-4159-9c33-c8b006282334" =         {
        "aba16653-bda0-4e89-b1c8-63df6faa7c10" =             (
            yes
        );
    };
    "d765038e-e85a-495d-9932-170852fbd86e" =         {
        "57646099-b717-4a2b-b9eb-2935548ae954" =             (
            yes
        );
        "957bdaba-b23d-4243-8384-62dfa46f0656" = play;
    };
};
"c81e7d71-6f1e-4b83-8740-c73ee52e3b0b" =     (
    2
);
}
```

Comment: Your string is not a valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks @Tander. but can you let me know what is incorrect in the JSON. This is what am getting from server

Comment: As mentioned, the JSOn is not valid. Use something like this: https://jsonlint.com to validate and check for errors

Comment: That '=' symbol in the string which you provided looks strange because it won't be '=' in a valid JSON string

Comment: `(yes)` That's strange for instance. Else, you can use subString, and check what's the surrounding string around 45, like NSString *whereLiesIssue = [yourString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(45-10,10)];. The "=", the ";" are not valid. I seems more like the description of a `NSDictionary` in Objective-C.

Comment: Valid JSON string for the string which you provided will be as follows :- "{\n \"40147089-db8b-4223-89ab-7a2f72ac57d6\" : {\n \"22337b85-d2cf-4079-8d5f-9804cb680f2c\" : (\n yes\n );\n \"87eeb49f-b34a-431b-8701-bd7f36bc91ea\" : (\n yes\n );\n };\n \"7262d43c-4d72-4e71-9097-6db5632d1f54\" : {\n \"22337b85-d2cf-4079-8d5f-9804cb680f2c\" : (\n yes\n );\n \"58ecb861-4372-412b-8740-a9f94260ed93\" : (\n yes\n );\n };\n}"

Comment: I have just replaced the '=' with ':'

Comment: Could you show the code from where you get that string? Because it really seems to be the description of already a dictionary. The `{}` for the dict, the `()` for the array, the `;` as delimitor, the `=` between keys and values... Doing `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", someDict]` will give a similar result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use NSJSONSerialization for your data.